# Angularjs 'indexOf' of undefined?

Tags: angularjs

I think $scope.tutor.noiday is an array, but i don't understand why i got that error. Please help me.

[This my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYxfM.png)

here is my code controller.js

```
$scope.daytai = ['Tutor house', 'Student house', 'Other'];
    $scope.dashbroadTutorInfo = function(){
        // find tutor by username - current_user
        $scope.username = $rootScope.current_user;
        $scope.tutor = tutorFactory.getTutorByUsername($scope.username)
        .then(function(response){
            if(response.data){
                $scope.tutor = response.data.giasu;
            }
        }); 
    }
  // check exist noiday
  $scope.existDay = function(item){
        return tutorFactory.exists($scope.tutor.noiday, item);
    }
```

this is my service.js

```
// check exist item in array
    tutorFactory.exists = function(arr, item){
        return arr.indexOf(item) > -1;
    }
```

html

```
<form ng-submit="updateJob()">
    <input type="hidden" ng-model="tutor._id">
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="noiday">Nơi dạy:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div ng-repeat="c in daytai">
                <label><input type="checkbox" name="" 
                   ng-model="tutor.noiday" ng-checked="existDay(c)" 
                   ng-click="selNoiDay(c)"/><span></span>{{c}}</label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
          <button type="submit" class="base-text-color">Submit</button>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the error message (which should be in the question, as text, rather than on a seperate web site, as an image) clearly shows that `arr` is undefined. How could we help?

Comment: Have you printed what `item` looks like when calling `existDay(c)`?

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$scope.dashbroadTutorInfo = function(){
    // find tutor by username - current_user
    $scope.username = $rootScope.current_user;
    tutorFactory.getTutorByUsername($scope.username)
    .then(function(response){
        if(response.data){
            $scope.tutor = response.data.giasu;
            // check exist noiday
            $scope.existDay = function(item){
                return tutorFactory.exists($scope.tutor.noiday, item);
            }
         }
    }); 
}
```

in factory

```
angular.module('yourApp')
.factory('tutorFactory', function($http) {
  var tutor = {};
  tutor.getTutorByUsername = function(username){
      return $http.get('your/path/'+username)
      .then(function(resp){
        return resp;
      }, function(resp){
      return resp;
    })
  }
  return tutor;
})
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now i know where is my mistake. I should put $scope.existDay inside $scope.dashbroadTutorInfo